# Как перенести рабочую SQLite БД из памяти Android-устройства на sd-карту?

Tags: android, sqlite, sd

Без переноса самого приложения.

Смысл состоит в том, что по мере пользования приложением, её база данных пополняясь увеличивается в размере, и может занимать ощутимое место в памяти устройства, что иногда приводит к известным последствиям (особенно на "несвежих" устройствах). Поэтому хочется добавить функцию переноса базы данных на SD-карту, и продолжения работы с ней на SD-карте.

Пока пишу такой замысел:

1. Приложение при первом запуске проверяет, есть ли на устройстве
   SD-карта.
2. Если SD-карта есть, то готовая sqlite БД сразу
   распаковывается на SD-карту, и приложение работает с БД на SD-карте.
3. Если SD-карта не обнаружена, то - понятно... но здесь засада,
   описанная выше - со временем может возникнуть проблема с
   недостаточностью памяти устройства.
4. Поэтому в приложении добавляю функцию переноса БД на SD-карту по решению пользователя (на тот
   случай, когда пользователь решил приобрести и установить SD-карту).

И вот главный вопрос: как реализовать сам перенос рабочей sqlite БД из памяти устройства на SD-карту, и затем продолжать с ней работать?

Comment: О каком устройстве идёт речь? Добавьте тэг.

Comment: главное, что не из чайника переносить :)

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете так:

1. БД Sqlite это обычный файл, по умолчанию находится в каталоге, на который указывает метод `Context.getDatabasePath()`
2. Копируете файл обычными файловыми средствами Java
3. При копировании надо иметь пермишен на чтение/запись на внешний носитель и озаботиться специальными мерами, если API level >= KitKat (гугль в помощь)
4. После копирования местонахождение БД указываете в перегруженном методе `Activity.getDatabasePath()` открываете его обычными средствами и юзаете.

Для копирования файла можно использовать такой метод:

```
public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    }
    finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Надеюсь, благодарить разрешается в комментариях...

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Благодарить надо не так :)